# discord.js the bot crash when there's no mention in my unmute command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so i made a mute and unmute command, the mute one works pretty well and i just gotta add some things, the unmute one also works well but when there's no mentioned person (for example q!unmute and not q!unmute [user]) the bot crashes, i tried catch and that stuff but i really don't understand how they work, i'm pretty new to js, this is the string that should send the "you have to mention a user" error:

```
if (!member) return message.channel.send("You have to mention a valid member");
```

this is the rest of the code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'unmute',
    description: 'unmutes a muted member',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {

        if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) {

            const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');
            const member = message.mentions.members.first();
            var unmuteChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.includes("modlogs"));

            const unmuteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .addField("Unmuted user", member)
            .setFooter(`Unmuted by ${message.author.tag}`)
            .setTimestamp();

            
            member.roles.remove(role);
            message.channel.send(`${member} Has Been Unmuted`);
            unmuteChannel.send(unmuteEmbed); 
        
        if (!member) return message.channel.send("You have to mention a valid member");

        }
        
    }
}
```

i hope you can help

Comment: Try to move the error handling to right after you set the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you're checking if the user mentioned is null, but it is at the end of the function. I think that putting the if just after you get the value should work:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'unmute',
    description: 'unmutes a muted member',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {

        if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) {

            const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');
            const member = message.mentions.members.first();
            if (!member) return message.channel.send("You have to mention a valid member");

            var unmuteChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.includes("modlogs"));

            const unmuteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .addField("Unmuted user", member)
            .setFooter(`Unmuted by ${message.author.tag}`)
            .setTimestamp();

            
            member.roles.remove(role);
            message.channel.send(`${member} Has Been Unmuted`);
            unmuteChannel.send(unmuteEmbed); 
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move

```js
if (!member) return message.channel.send("You have to mention a valid member");
```

Below where you define member.

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```